# How do I make curl.js resolve circular dependencies?

Tags: amd, circular-dependency, curl.js

I've got two `AMD` modules which should reference each other, but as soon as I add backward dependency, it stops working. I suppose it got stuck in `waiting` state.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/curl.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      curl(['m1', 'm2'], function(m1, m2) {
          console.log('done', m1, m2);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`m1.js`:

```
define(['m2'], function() {
    return 1;
});
```

`m2.js`

```
define(['m1'], function() {
    return 2;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD** It appears I was wrong and `curl.js` doesn't always resolve [circular dependencies](https://github.com/cujojs/curl/issues/262#issuecomment-38858593).

---

You should declare it in `CommonJS` way:

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/curl.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      curl(['m1', 'm2'], function(m1, m2) {
          console.log('done', m1.v, m2.v);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`m1.js`:

```
define(function(require, exports) {
    var m2 = require('m2');
    exports.v = 1;
});
```

`m2.js`

```
define(function(require, exports) {
    var m1 = require('m1');
    exports.v = 2;
});
```

Another option is to mix the approaches (`AMD`, `CommonJS`):

`m1.js`:

```
define(function(require) {
    var m2 = require('m2');
    return 1;
});
```

**UPD** But there might be some problems. I haven't yet figured out what's happening. I've created [an issue](https://github.com/cujojs/curl/issues/262) for one of them for now.

Comment: Very nice example.  Just a note: your use of a leading slash on the module ids (e.g. "/3.js") tells curl that they are urls, not ids.  Also, the use of ".js" is discouraged and causes some AMD loaders to use different url resolution rules.

Comment: @unscriptable But if I omit the leading slash, they will be searched for relative to the current page, or not?